# SAS JMP to R integration: get R ggplot output into JMP with R Submit File

Tags: r, ggplot2, sas-jmp

I find that if I want to import ggplot output from R into JMP using JSL scripting that I run into a problem. In JSL, I used the `R Submit File` call to directly call an existing R file, rather than repeating the R script in the JSL script (this can be done by e.g. using the `R Submit` JSL function).
One can ask why one would want to import an R plot into JMP as JMP has a fantastic graphics engine. I just noted this issue during a trial with JMP to R integration and thought it was good to share.
I initially raised this issue in the JMP community pages; this is a summary.

Here's the JSL:

```
LoadExprs = Expr(
    InitR = Expr(
        R Init();
    );

    RunR = Expr(
        R Submit File( "C:\R_projects\JMP\R_JPM_integration_1.R" );
    );
    
    CapturePlot = Expr(
        JMP_plot = R Get Graphics( png );
        New Window( "Imported Plot", Picture Box( JMP_Plot ) );
    );
        
    RunClose = Expr(
        Wait(5);
        R Term(); //Close r connection
    );
);
LoadExprs;
InitR;
RunR;
CapturePlot;
RunClose;
```

Here's the R code (just simple test code)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(palmerpenguins)

ggplot(data = penguins, aes(x = bill_length_mm, y = flipper_length_mm, colour = species)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(. ~ island, nrow = 3)
```

This causes the error code `Get data for "png" failed` to arise in JMP.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that we just need to explicitly plot the ggplot object in R as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(palmerpenguins)

p <- ggplot(data = penguins, aes(x = bill_length_mm, y = flipper_length_mm, colour = species)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(. ~ island, nrow = 3)
plot(p)
```

The ggplot plot now comes across to JMP as a png without any error message.